# How can I make this Ruby puzzle solution faster?

Tags: ruby, optimization, puzzle

One reason I hate puzzle sites is because they tell you when you fail but you can't learn how to improve. I typically don't like posting these kinds of questions, but I wasted so much time trying to figure out why this fails I MUST KNOW the answer!

Here is my code:

```
ARGF.each do |line|
  if ARGF.lineno > 1
    string_a = line.strip
    string_b = line.strip
    sum = string_a.size
    (0...string_a.size).each do |i|
      string_b[0] = '' 
      (0...string_b.size).each do |j|
        break if string_a[j] != string_b[j]
        sum = sum + 1 
      end 
    end
    puts sum
  end
end
```

Here is the problem (if your curious): http://pastie.org/3044657

It passes most tests but then fails afterward due to optimization reasons. I would LOVE to know how to optimize this. I don't know how to go about "identifying and learning" how to optimize.

PS. This is the most entry-level puzzle so I highly doubt it is hurting anyone by walking through this.

Comment: http://pastie.org/3044657 doesn't work. Are you sure the link is correct?

Comment: Could we see the tests your answer is failing? And did you try profiling the code if by optimisations you mean execution speed?

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is O(n²). There is not much you can do about this by just optimizing the code.

Some ideas to slightly improve the performance for the given algorithm:

- Split the string into an array.
- Once you have found a `j` with `string_a[j] != string_b[j]`, increment `sum` by that `j`
  instead of counting each equal pair.

This code is about twice as fast as your's on my machine for my test cases:

```
ary = line.strip.chars.to_a
n = ary.count
sum = (1...n).inject(n) do | sum, i |
  sum + (n-i).times { | j | break j if ary[j] != ary[j + i] }
end
```

Comment: this is essentially still O(n^2) though. I guess I will have to figure out how to make it faster than that. EIther O(n) or O log n

Comment: @darkone: Yes, of course it's O(n²) -- it's the same algorithm.

Comment: yeah. Surprisingly your solution is also too slow. Makes me wonder if I am overlooking something obvious.